# Variable retaining value between macro calls

Tags: excel, vba

new programmer with a question for more experienced heads. I'm using Office 365 ProPlus.

I have a variable that is sometimes retaining its value between calls of the macro.  The variable in question is a counter, which I had created to confirm that my for loop was running the number of times I intended. At the end of the macro, the value of the counter would output to a cell in my worksheet. I began to notice that instead of giving me the same answer every time, the cell value was incrementing by the number of iterations in the loop after each call of the macro (e.g. for a loop with five iterations, after the first call my counter would equal 5, after the second call 10, after the third 15, and so on). If I stop the macro in the middle, say to make a change and then rerun, the counter resets to 0.

Here are the relevant sections of code:

```
Option explicit
Public Counter As Integer
Sub MyMacro()
Call Looper
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("g2") = Counter
End Sub

Sub Looper()
Dim k as Integer
For k = 33 to 4044
Counter = Counter + 1
         'Nonrelevant code
Next k
End Sub
```

The above code has all active uses of the variable not including message boxes.

I put message boxes before and after calling my loop sub in case it had something to do with how the counter was printing to the cell, but the message box before the loop displays the result of the previous call, and the message box after the loop has been incremented by the number of loops.  I also added a watch expression for Counter, and unless I have reset counter by interrupting the process as mentioned above, as soon as the sub begins the value of Counter jumps to what it was at the end of the previous call.

I can set the starting value of counter to 0, but why is the counter starting with a value at all?

Comment: global variable will retain it's value for the life of the excel session. part of why global variables are frowned upon. either reset it or declare and use it in the looper function.

Comment: @bryan60 I believe a global variable retain's its value for as long as the macro is running, but the value is not guaranteed to hold its state beyond the end of macro execution. In any case, it's something to be avoided

Comment: @bryan60, for the whole excel session?  I thought that it just lasted the length of the macro, as PeterT said. What do you do when you want a variable to be available to multiple modules?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-the-lifetime-of-variables